# Java 8 Streams, put an element at the top of the list, and then sort alphabetically by name

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of items (users id)

```
List<String> userUid= Arrays.asList("uid1", "uid3", "uid5", "uid2", "uid4", "uid0");
```

How can I put for example "uid2" at the top of the list, and then sort the list? So the new list would be:

uid2, uid0, uid1, uid3, uid4, uid5.

I tried with no success `userUid.sort(Comparator.comparing("uid2"::equals).reversed());`

The problem with this is that it will show at the top of the list the last element of the old list.

To explain more I want to make a list of users and I want to show at the top of this list the user that is logged in. And then sort the list alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom comparator for this:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
     if (o1.equals("uid2")) return -1;
     if (o2.equals("uid2"))return 1;
     return o1.compareTo(o2);
   };
Collections.sort(userUid,comparator);
```

or you can do like this:

```
List<String> res =  userUid.stream().sorted()
       .filter(u -> !u.equals("uid2"))
       .collect(ArrayList::new,
              (l, s) ->{if (l.isEmpty())l.add("uid2");l.add(s);},
              List::addAll );
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement your comparator such that, when the element equals the currentUserUid, it is smallest, otherwise compare them alphabetically.

```
public class CustomSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> userUid = Arrays.asList("uid1", "uid3", "uid5", "uid2", "uid4", "uid0");
        final String currentUserUid = "uid2";
        userUid.sort((uid1, uid2) -> {
            if (uid1.equals(uid2)) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (uid1.equals(currentUserUid)) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (uid2.equals(currentUserUid)) {
                return 1;
            }
            return uid1.compareTo(uid2);
        });
        System.out.println(userUid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

- Remove the user's id from the list of names.
- Sort the names
- Add the user's id to the front of the list

Something like this:

```
List<String> userUid= Arrays.asList("uid1", "uid3", "uid5", "uid2", "uid4", "uid0");
List<String> sortedIds = Stream.concat(Stream.of("uid2"), userUid.stream()
           .filter(id -> !"uid2".equals(id)) // in java-11 use Predicate::not
           .sorted())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```