# How to batch update arrays?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I am creating an attendance app in which there is a list named attendees which contains the list of all students attending the lecture.

```dart
List<String> attendees = [uid0, uid1, uid2];
```

and the student data model is as follows

```dart
Student(
List<String> attendance = [at0, at1]; //this is the list of lectures attended
String name;
)
```

and the document name of every student is their user-id
How do I update the list of every student via the `batch()` function?

Comment: Is this by any means [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569768/java-8-streams-put-an-element-at-the-top-of-the-list-and-then-sort-alphabetica)? Or is the similarity of the data structures just coincidence?

Comment: No, it is not related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have a list of attendees that contains `user-id` as you mentioned the `userId` would be the `documentId` in Firestore.

Therefore, you can do a loop and `update` your doc directly and then use `commit` to apply your changes.

```dart
updateBatch(List<String> attendees) async {
  try {
    final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    final WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

    // based on this doc https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#batch-write
    // Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents.
    for (final userid in attendees) {
      // Use the batch to update a document that exist otherwise it will throw error,
      // in case you want to create that doc, maybe you should use `set` instead
      // ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch/update.html
      batch.update(
        //Give the ref of document.
        db.document('Path/to/firestore/document'),  // e.g: /Students/userId
        //And the data to update.
        {"key": value},
      );
    }

    await batch.commit();
    print('success');
  } catch (e) {
    print('error $e');
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- According to [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents.
- You can check out [different WriteBatch methods doc here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html)